# Regex: Match/Delete everything on a line except parenthesis (keep the parentheses and delete the rest of the words on the line)

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have this kind of line:

`Word (mother) word 33 (453) word word 444 (4) word`

The result should be: `(mother) (453) (4)`

I want to keep the parentheses and delete the rest of the words on the line. I try this regex, but not too good :(

Search: `\([^!(]*?\)|\(|\)`

Replace by: `\1`

Comment: Please post the result you want to achieve for the example above.

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^|\G)(?:\h*\w+\h*)+(\(\w+\)\h*)|(?:\h*\w+)*$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
  (?:^|\G)      # non capture group, beginning of line OR restart from last match position
  (?:           # non capture group
    \h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
    \w+         # 1 or more word characters
    \h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  )+            # end group, may appear 1 or more times
  (             # start group 1
    \(\w+\)     # 1 or more word characters surounded by parenthesis
    \h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  )             # end group 1
|               # OR
  (?:           # non capture group
    \h*\w+      # 0 or more horizontal spaces, followed by 1 or more word characters
  )*            # group may appear 0 or more times
  $             # end of line
```

**Result for given example:**

```
(mother) (453) (4)
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex to extract a word with its parenthesis is:

```
\(([^)]+)\)
```

Answer (score 1):

first replace

edited:

```
.*?(\(.*?\))
```

with

```
\1
```

then, replace

```
^(.*\)).*
```

with

```
\1
```

Final output

```
(mother)(453)(4)
```

Comment: What's the meaning of the first quotation mark? Did you really try it?

Comment: You are right. That was wrong regex. As I had done it in two parts, the first regex was copied to clipboard but got mixed up when I pasted here from clipboard. Now edited to post the correct one. I am sorry for the mistake. I appreciate your highlighting the error in time.